# convert month numeric form into their name?

Tags: python, templates, django-templates

I was using this code to print the month.
In **views.py**

> currentMonth = datetime.now().month
>        return render_to_response('showroom.html',{'currentMonth':currentMonth,} ,
>   context_instance=RequestContext(request))

after that **print** the variable **{{currentMonth}}** in our file.
**It shows 12  but i want to show december.**

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number

Comment: when i am using 

    **import datetime
    currentMonth = datetime.now().month
    currentMonthn = currentMonth.strftime("%B")**

It throughs **error**
**'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
# Near the top of views.py
from datetime import datetime

# ...
currentMonth = datetime.now().strftime('%B')
return render_to_response('showroom.html',{'currentMonth':currentMonth,} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the code you have in your comment above:

```
import datetime
currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentMonthn = currentMonth.strftime("%B")
```

`currentMonth` is an integer, and does not have the `strftime` method, but `datetime.now()` returns an object that does:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%B')
'December'
>>>
```