# date handling issue in Python

Tags: python, date, calendar, return

I'm working on a project that deals with dates. The user enters the month (in terms of a number - so "3", not "March") and a year (2005), and then it returns "March 2005 has 31 days. I'm nearly finished, but instead of returning the name of the month, it returns the number. So it says:

3 2005 has 31 days.

Here's my code:

```
def enteredMonth():
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    if month == 1:
        month = "January"
    elif month == 2:
        month = "February"
    elif month == 3:
        month = "March"
    elif month == 4:
        month = "April"
    elif month == 5:
        month = "May"
    elif month == 6:
        month = "June"
    elif month == 7:
        month = "July"
    elif month == 8:
        month = "August"
    elif month == 9:
        month = "September"
    elif month == 10:
        month = "October"
    elif month == 11:
        month = "November"
    elif month == 12:
        month = "December"
    return month

def main():
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    print(month, year, "has", numberOfDays(month, year) , "days")
```

How do I tweak the code so it returns the name of the month, not the number that the user entered?

Please help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Put the result in a separate variable, and return that instead.  FWIW, a dictionary probably works better here.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you edit in? Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is there any way to do it without using that method?

Comment: If this is not an exercise: `return datetime.date(1970, month, 1).strftime("%B")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your function, `enteredMonth()`, but never use it in your code.

```
print(enteredMonth(month), year, "has", numberOfDays(month, year), "days")
```

But a much better way to optimize `enteredMonth` is by simply using a dictionary:

```
months = {
    1: 'January'
    2: 'February'
    ...
}
```

Then you can access each month's string with its number, like so:

```
>>> months[1]
'January'
>>> months[4]
'April'
```

Comment: @akaRem how would I use a tuple?

Comment: {1:<1>, 2:<2>, ..} -> (<1>, <2>, ...), so .. indexing works, add/append/pop does not, but you don't need it in case of months

Comment: @akaRem except indices start at 0, which raises the problems I brought up under Oscar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
def getmonthname:
    months = ['January', 'February', ... , 'December']
    return months[month - 1]
```