# Convert pandas datetime month to string representation

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to have a pandas DataFrame with a timestamp column and want to create a column with just the month. I want to have the month column with string representations of the month, not with integers. I have done something like this:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df['Month'] = df.Dates.dt.month
df['Month'] = df.Month.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%m').strftime('%b'))
```

However, this is some kind of a brute force approach and not very performant. Is there a more elegant way to convert the integer representation of the month into a string representation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use vectorised [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) on your datetimes:

```
In [43]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,1), dt.datetime(2017,2,1), freq='M')})
df

Out[43]:
        dates
0  2016-01-31
1  2016-02-29
2  2016-03-31
3  2016-04-30
4  2016-05-31
5  2016-06-30
6  2016-07-31
7  2016-08-31
8  2016-09-30
9  2016-10-31
10 2016-11-30
11 2016-12-31
12 2017-01-31

In [44]:    
df['month'] = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%b')
df

Out[44]:
        dates month
0  2016-01-31   Jan
1  2016-02-29   Feb
2  2016-03-31   Mar
3  2016-04-30   Apr
4  2016-05-31   May
5  2016-06-30   Jun
6  2016-07-31   Jul
7  2016-08-31   Aug
8  2016-09-30   Sep
9  2016-10-31   Oct
10 2016-11-30   Nov
11 2016-12-31   Dec
12 2017-01-31   Jan
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach with the np.datetime64 format of my 'Dates' column I get when using the `df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])` ?

Comment: When I use this solution, I get the following error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime`. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, seems like I got an older pandas version, that does not support this type of conversion.

Comment: how about the inverse operation?

Comment: @famargar You just do `pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%b')` this will just generate a default datetime with that month

Answer (score 8):

For versions `pandas 0.23.0+` is possible use [`dt.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html):

```
df['month'] = df['dates'].dt.month_name()
print (df)

        dates      month
0  2016-01-31    January
1  2016-02-29   February
2  2016-03-31      March
3  2016-04-30      April
4  2016-05-31        May
5  2016-06-30       June
6  2016-07-31       July
7  2016-08-31     August
8  2016-09-30  September
9  2016-10-31    October
10 2016-11-30   November
11 2016-12-31   December
12 2017-01-31    January
```