# Python: Converting a day number to a day name using calendar

Tags: python, date, calendar

Using the following command I was able to get the numerical day of the week for a given date:

```
from calendar import weekday

print(weekday(2015, 5, 8))
```

This block then produces the number `4`. How can I convert this into `Friday`, preferably just using the calendar library. I've looked through the documentation as best as I can but couldn't find anything that would print out the full day name.

Cheers.

Comment: What is `inp` used for?

Comment: you haven't tried enough, but look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577516

Comment: @LutzHorn My mistake, was left there by accident. I have removed it now.

Comment: @Evan-Peters The question was about week days, not months ...

Comment: Sorry about that. My bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`calendar.day_name`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) which is a list of week days in current locale:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.day_name[4]
'Friday'
```

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I've found an answer but I'll leave the question up if anyone else is curious. The calendar library has an array called `day_name` with the days of the week in it:

> `An array that represents the days of the week in the current locale.`

I was able to get the day by using:

```
from calendar import weekday, day_name

dayNumber = weekday(2015, 5, 8)
dayName = day_name[dayNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a good way to solve

```
import calendar
print((calendar.day_name[calendar.weekday(2019, 9, 12)]).upper())
```