# Write a basic program that takes number and returns its corresponding month abbreviation

Tags: python, indexing, error-handling, except

I'm trying to write a basic function that takes a number and returns the abbreviation of each month. It sounds simple enough, but how can I use a "try-except"block to handle any exceptions?

Here's what I have so far.

```
def month():
    months = "JanFebMarchAprilMayJuneJulyAugSepOctNovDec"
    n = eval(input("Enter month Number: "))
    pos = (n-1)*3
    monthAbbrev = months

    return monthAbbrev
```

I guess my question is how can I put in a try-expect handle indexes that are out of range?
I'm completely lost here. Thanks for your help

Comment: Not all your months are abbreviations.. And why not just use a list instead of a long string?

Answer (score 1):

This simply returns the month at the correct index and if it doesn't exist it retruns the String `Error` replace it by whatever you need.

```
def month(n):
        months = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ...)
        try:
            return months[n-1]
        except IndexError:
            return "Error"
```

Comment: Please do **not** play Pokemon exception handling. You do **not** want to catch them all. Catch just the `IndexError` exception that a wrong index would throw, nothing else, you don't want to mask `MemoryError` or `KeyboardInterrupt` here, for example.

Answer (score -1):

import datetime
mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
mydate.strftime("%b")

[Get month name from number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number)

Surround that with a try except to catch any errors