# The assignment: Prompt user to input their Birthmonth then input the day they were born. Print the month's name followed by the day

Tags: python, loops, date, names

I tried doing it the long way by simply going down the months one by one but my teacher told me the long was was unacceptable. Now I have the day and month printed but am not sure how to quickly change the number given into the month it represents. This is what I have so far.

```
    birthMonth = int(input("Enter your Birth Month:"))

if birthMonth <= 0 or birthMonth > 12:
   print("Invalid, Choose again")
else:
    birthDay = int(input("What day?:"))
    if birthDay <=0 or birthDay > 31:
        print('Not a valid Birthday')
    else:
        print(birthMonth, birthDay)
```

It will print the number and the day which is fine but she does not want me to list out all of the months. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module to get the month associated with a number.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> month_num = 8
>>> month = datetime.date(2017, month_num, 1).strftime("%B")
>>> print(month)
August
```

Another alternative (probably the better one) is to use the `calendar` module

```
>>> import calendar
>>> month_num = 8
>>> calendar.month_name[month_num]
August
```

So, in your code, you can replace

```
print(birthMonth, birthDay)
```

with

```
print(calendar.month_name[birthMonth], birthDay)
```

but, make sure that you import the `calendar` module.

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you double for answering so quickly ^^