# Python : how do I add a date into this

Tags: python

I got this, but how to insert a date into it,  the date i want is one month from current time

```
print（'''

{} will play football on Y

'''.format(name1))
```

whereby the Y is one month later from the current time

Comment: Take a look at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: To get the current month of the year, use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().month
8
```

Where [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) gets the current time as a `datetime` object, and the `.month` attribute prints the current month (as a number)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import *
monthNames=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
name1 = str(input("Please input your name: "))
thisMonth = int(datetime.now().month)
thisMonth_name = monthNames[thisMonth]

print("%s will play football on %s" %(name1, thisMonth_name))
```

OR

```
import datetime as dt
import calendar
name1 = str(input("Please input your name: "))
thisMonth = int(dt.datetime.now().month)+1
monthName = str(calendar.month_name[thisMonth])

print("%s will play football on %s" %(name1, monthName))
```

> Also see: [Get month name from number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number)
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name

Comment: Adding 1 to the month won't work in December. You can do `thisMonth %=  12`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, can you please give the full syntax of the code where I can do `thisMonth%=12` so that this code works in December as well?

Comment: Put that exact line, `thisMonth %= 12`, just below `thisMonth = int(dt.datetime.now().month)+1`. To be clear, in case you're not familiar with the operation, that is equivalent to `thisMonth = thisMonth % 12`, which, in December, divides 13 by 12 and returns the remainder, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Often the easiest way of manipulating dates and times in ways like this is to use the [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. In this case, you can get what you want with this code:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.now().shift(months=+1).format('MMMM')
'September'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print datetime one month later from current time,

you can use `datetime` and `dateutil` in combination.

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
today = datetime.today()
monthplus1 = today + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
print today
print monthplus1
# output
> datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 31, 8, 52, 3, 75585)
> datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 8, 52, 3, 75585)
```

then you can use the datetime attributes like `monthplus1.month` to get the next month.
and if you want names of the month, use a list like in below answer

`monthNames=["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]`

with little tweak, so the 0th will be empty and you can get the Month Names

```
monthNames[monthplus1.month]
> 'September'
```

Then use these values as you would normaly do using format

```
print（'''

{} will play football on {}

'''.format(name1, monthNames[monthplus1.month]))
```