# Want to convert string date to date time and split it into two columns of year and month_date

Tags: python, pandas, date

My dataframe has a column of dates like 2014-11-12. 
I want to split it into two columns: **Year** and **Month_date** and put year as **2014** in 'Year column' and **Nov 12** in 'Month_date' column. [I have split Date column but not able to put in '**Nov 12**' format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ8D2.png). I am new to python. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: using `df.Date.dt.month`, and build a dict like`{1:'Jan',2:'Feb'...}` athen using `map`

Comment: This may be a repeated question & answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number ... It would help also if you provided some of your code... If you are asking what I think, you have 2 options as far as I know: **(1)** Use full name of month, which would require you to import `datetime` and use `.strftime('%B')`. **(2)** Use abbreviations.  In this case you should create your own system using an array.  Basically, have your month number correspond to an index of an array containing the abbreviations (this is pretty basic, but ask if you don't understand)

Comment: Please... How hard is it to just paste some of your data here? Do you really want to make it difficult for people to answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month-Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
print (df)
            ID       Date  Data_Value  Year Month-Date
0  USW00094889 2014-11-12          22  2014      11-12
1  USC00208972 2009-04-29          56  2009      04-29
2  USC00200032 2008-05-26         278  2008      05-26
3  USC00205563 2005-11-11         139  2005      11-11
4  USC00200230 2014-02-27        -106  2014      02-27
5  USW00014833 2010-10-01         194  2010      10-01
6  USC00207308 2010-06-29         144  2010      06-29
```

---

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month-Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%d')
print (df)
            ID       Date  Data_Value  Year Month-Date
0  USW00094889 2014-11-12          22  2014     Nov-12
1  USC00208972 2009-04-29          56  2009     Apr-29
2  USC00200032 2008-05-26         278  2008     May-26
3  USC00205563 2005-11-11         139  2005     Nov-11
4  USC00200230 2014-02-27        -106  2014     Feb-27
5  USW00014833 2010-10-01         194  2010     Oct-01
6  USC00207308 2010-06-29         144  2010     Jun-29
```

Comment: Are you sure? Downvotes means really bad answer. So why it was accepted?

Comment: your answer is perfect, Thanks again