# Increment the month in python and then print the name of the incremented month

Tags: python, python-datetime

Is there any way to print the name of the incremented month?

```
import datetime
currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
currentmonth=currentDT.strftime("%B")
nextmonth = datetime.date.today().month + 1
```

Here I get the "nextmonth" in form of integer.

```
7
```

But how can I get the name of that month i.e. July. I even tried using this,

```
next_month=nextmonth.strftime("%B")
```

But it returned the error,

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get month name from number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number)

Comment: But,  how do I get the name of the incremented month.

Comment: You know how to get the index of the next month. From there you can use the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`calendar` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)

```
import calendar
print (calendar.month_name[4])
```

It is built-in.

Comment: OP already imports datetime so why not use datetime functionality?

Comment: Would be a better approach, using `datetime`

Comment: The `calendar` module is definitely the correct approach, regardless of how many times the user has imported datetime (or any other modules).

Answer (score 0):

For edge cases like December as `calendar.month_name` has 13 elements

```
import calendar
import datetime
months=calendar.month_name[1:]
a=months[datetime.date.today().month % 12]
print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that `nextmonth` is an `int` representing month number, not `date` object, so you can use [`calendar.month_name` array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) like

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.month_name[(datetime.date.today().month + 1) % 12]
'July'
```

Comment: Fails for December

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this in python 3

```
import time,datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
currentmonth=currentDT.strftime("%B")
nextmonth = datetime.date.today().month + 1
print(time.strftime('%B', time.struct_time((0, nextmonth, 0,)+(0,)*6)))
```

Comment: Your code at `print(time.strftime('%B', time.struct_time((0, nextmonth, 0,)+(0,)*6)))`  raise an exception: `Exception has occurred: ValueError
strftime() requires year in [1; 9999]`. Do you mean: `print(time.strftime('%B', time.struct_time((1, nextmonth, 0,)+(0,)*6)))` ?