# Get months from a given date in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I want to get only the months from the given date. For example, given a date 2021-02-14, to be transformed to 'February'.

Comment: near-dupe: [Get month name from number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6557553/10197418), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557568/10197418).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.strftime` with `%B` to get the month name as you need

See an example below,

```
import datetime

date = "2020-01-01"

date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime.strftime(date_obj, "%B") # January
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the Number of the month by datetime.datetime.month. To make this into the String 'February', you would need a dictionary.  See the docs of the datetime class for more information.