# Read specified amount of lines compute a total then continue reading

Tags: python, list, loops

How do i get a function to read a certain amount of lines and then compute a total by adding up the numbers from those lines printing it then looping to read the next lines etc. The function opens up a file that has hundreds of lines with numbers on them.

Example:

```
def open_input_file():
    while True:
        name_of_file = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
        try:
            file_wanted = open(name_of_file, 'r')
            return file_wanted
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"The file {name_of_file} was not found. Check the file name and try again.")


def average_steps(read_file, amount_of_days):
    open(read_file.name, 'r')
    amount_of_lines = len(open(read_file.name).readlines(amount_of_days))

    total = 0
    for line in read_file:
        num = int(line)
        total += num

    average = total / amount_of_lines
    return average


def main():
    file_wanted = open_input_file()
    month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                  'October', 'November', 'December']
    day_list = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    day_being_used = 0
    month_being_used = 0
    months = 12

    for month_being_used in range(months):
        steps = average_steps(file_wanted, day_list[day_being_used])
        print(f"The average steps taken in {month_list[month_being_used]} was {steps} ")
        day_being_used += 1
        month_being_used += 1
    file_wanted.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys


def open_input_file():

file_wanted = None
while file_wanted is None:
    name_of_file = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
    try:
        file_wanted = open(name_of_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
        return file_wanted
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"The file {name_of_file} was not found. Check the file name and try again.")


def average_steps(file, day):

count = day
total = 0
try:
    for i in range(day):
        line = file.readline()
        num = int(line)
        total += num
    average = total / count
    return average
except ValueError:
    print("The program has aborted because the steps file contains invalid data.")
    print("The error is: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''")
    sys.exit(1)


def main():

file_object = open_input_file()
month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
              'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
              'October', 'November', 'December']
day_list = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

day_being_used = 0

for month_being_used in range(len(month_list)):
    avg_steps = average_steps(file_object, day_list[day_being_used])

    print(f"The average steps taken in {month_list[month_being_used]} was {avg_steps: 7,.0f} ")
    day_being_used += 1
    month_being_used += 1

file_object.close()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

Comment: You should mark it as correct too!

Answer (score 0):

I feel it simplifies some of the logic if we just [read the whole file into a list using list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHFWb_6fHOw). It also seemed like you were opening the file 3 times in the code(or 25 times if we count each time it's opened in the loop). Once should be enough.

Once you have the data in a list, it's possible to just take [slices of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing) for each month. With a list you can also use python functions like [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to handle the average calculation.

I put the [following online here](https://www.online-python.com/kSQO2lXn7I) with 'nums' as the file full of numbers.

```
def open_input_file():
    while True:
        name_of_file = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
        try:
            file_wanted = open(name_of_file, 'r')
            return file_wanted
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"The file {name_of_file} was not found. Check the file name and try again.")




def main():
    file_wanted = open_input_file()
    month_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                  'October', 'November', 'December']
    day_list = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    day_being_used = 0
    month_being_used = 0

    # The file was already opened. Let's read all lines into a list.
    all_daily_steps = [int(line) for line in file_wanted]
    
    for month_being_used in range(len(month_list)):
        
        # For each month we'll create a new list from all_daily_steps. 
        # The new list will start after the sum of days in all previous months. Ex. The March list would start at the 59th element in the all_daily_steps list (31+28=59)
        list_slice_start = sum(day_list[:month_being_used])

        # It ends after that sum plus the days in the current month
        list_sclice_end = list_slice_start + day_list[day_being_used]

        # Now we're ready to make our new list for the current month 
        current_month_list_slice = all_daily_steps[list_slice_start : list_sclice_end]

        # Sum all the step values in the list divided by the number of of values
        avg_steps = sum(current_month_list_slice)/len(current_month_list_slice)
        
        print(f"The average steps taken in {month_list[month_being_used]} was {avg_steps}")
        day_being_used += 1
        month_being_used += 1
        
    file_wanted.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The tricky thing with defining the days_list is that pesky leap year business. [The Datetime library could probably help](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-14.php) you out here if we knew the year being referenced. [The calendar library is also useful for working with month names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557570/1586014).

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. But is there a way to have a function called def average in there that accepts the file name and the day/ amount of lines wanted to be read. Like have the program do the same thing but it would have a main, open_input_file, and average_steps(file_name, days) function

Comment: "day/ amount of lines wanted to be read"

You mean the number of days in each month? Does it always read all the days in a whole year anyway?

Or do you want to be able to tell it to read an arbitrary number of days? Like just the first 6 months of the year?

Is this a school assignment where you're required to pass only (file_name, days) to the average steps function? That changes a lot. If it's really file name that we need to pass, and not the opened file, then we'd have to call the open file function inside the average steps function.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem! How did you do it?

Comment: I posted the answer above.